# CMake не генерирует файл статической библиотеки .a

Tags: cmake

Подскажите, пожалуйста – замучился уже совсем. Почему в результате работы CMake с данным CMakeLists я не получаю файл статической библиотеки .a? Компилятор – MinGW-w64.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(minhook LANGUAGES C)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(MINHOOK_MAJOR_VERSION 1)
set(MINHOOK_MINOR_VERSION 3)
set(MINHOOK_PATCH_VERSION 3)
set(MINHOOK_VERSION ${MINHOOK_MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINHOOK_MINOR_VERSION}.${MINHOOK_PATCH_VERSION})

################
#    BUILD     # 
################

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "build shared version" OFF)

set(SOURCES_MINHOOK 
  "src/buffer.c"
  "src/hook.c"
  "src/trampoline.c"
)

if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  set(SOURCES_HDE "src/hde/hde64.c")
else()
  set(SOURCES_HDE "src/hde/hde32.c")
endif()

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(RESOURCES 
    "dll_resources/minhook.rc"
    "dll_resources/minhook.def"
  )
endif()

add_library(minhook SHARED ${SOURCES_MINHOOK} ${SOURCES_HDE} ${RESOURCES})

target_include_directories(minhook PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

target_include_directories(minhook PRIVATE "src/")
target_include_directories(minhook PRIVATE "src/hde/")

if(WIN32)
  set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
  if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)   
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX ".x64d")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX ".x64")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES RELWITHDEBINFO_POSTFIX ".x64")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES MINSIZEREL_POSTFIX ".x64")
  else()
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX ".x32d")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES RELEASE_POSTFIX ".x32")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES RELWITHDEBINFO_POSTFIX ".x32")
    set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES MINSIZEREL_POSTFIX ".x64")
  endif()
else()
  set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES PREFIX "lib")
  set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES POSTFIX "")
  set_target_properties(minhook PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")
endif()

target_link_libraries(minhook)

################
# CMAKE CONFIG # 
################

configure_package_config_file(
    "cmake/minhook-config.cmake.in"
    "minhook-config.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION 
    "lib/minhook"
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  "minhook-config-version.cmake"
VERSION 
  ${MINHOOK_VERSION}
COMPATIBILITY
  AnyNewerVersion
)

install(
  FILES 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/minhook-config.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/minhook-config-version.cmake"
  DESTINATION 
    "lib/minhook"
)

###################
#     INSTALL     #
###################

install(TARGETS minhook
        EXPORT minhook-targets
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib"
)

install(
  EXPORT
    minhook-targets
  NAMESPACE 
    minhook::
  DESTINATION 
    "lib/minhook"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include DESTINATION .
)
```

Содержимое CMakeCache.txt

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: d:/minhook-master/res
# It was generated by CMake: D:/Programs/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//build shared version
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_ADDR2LINE:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/addr2line.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/ar.exe

//Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
// MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//C compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc-ar.exe

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc-ranlib.exe

//Flags used by the C compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the C compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the C compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C applications.
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_DLLTOOL:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/dlltool.exe

//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Convert GNU import libraries to MS format (requires Visual Studio)
CMAKE_GNUtoMS:BOOL=OFF

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/minhook

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/ld.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/nm.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/objcopy.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/objdump.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=minhook

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/ranlib.exe

//RC compiler
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/windres.exe

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_READELF:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/readelf.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=OFF

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=OFF

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/strip.exe

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
minhook_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=D:/minhook-master/res

//Value Computed by CMake
minhook_IS_TOP_LEVEL:STATIC=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
minhook_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=D:/minhook-master


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_ADDR2LINE
CMAKE_ADDR2LINE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR
CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=d:/minhook-master/res
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=22
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=D:/Programs/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=D:/Programs/CMake/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=D:/Programs/CMake/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMAKE_C_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_DLLTOOL
CMAKE_DLLTOOL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to cache edit program executable.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=D:/Programs/CMake/bin/cmake-gui.exe
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=MinGW Makefiles
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=D:/minhook-master
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_NM
CMAKE_NM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJCOPY
CMAKE_OBJCOPY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJDUMP
CMAKE_OBJDUMP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RANLIB
CMAKE_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER_WORKS:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_READELF
CMAKE_READELF-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.22
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STRIP
CMAKE_STRIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Comment: дык, ты же собираешь динамическую библиотеку, а не статическую: `add_library(minhook SHARED...`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, откровенно говоря, я уже и SHARED, и STATIC пробовал, и вообще убирать ключевые слова из add_library – все бесполезно...

Comment: «Не верю ©…» и что собирается при завене `SHARED` на `STATIC`? какие ошибки? собираешь точно mingw'шным тулчейном, а не msvc?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, судя по всему, целевой файл должен иметь название minhook. По факту ни одного файла с таким именем я не получаю. Лишь большое число разных файлов от CMake вроде CMakeCache, Log, *.cmake. Сам CMake тоже не указывает на какие-либо проблемы.

The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info

Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: D:/Tools/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Configuring done
Generating done

Comment: эмм... а собственно сборку (`make`) ты запустил? ну и если всё так, то лог конфигурации и сборки в студию...

Comment: Дык там `.a.x32` генерируются, наверное?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, конечно, не исключено, что я что-то делаю не так. Но вроде все примитивно: запустить CMake-gui, указать директорию с CMakeLists.txt и директорию размещения целевых файлов, тыкнуть Configure и Generate. Собрать пытаюсь это проект –> https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook.

Comment: @arrowd, к сожалению, даже .a.x32 нет.

Comment: @arrowd, я бы советовал запускать `cmake` вручную, а не через `cmake-gui`, но по большому счёту это дело вкуса... лог конфигурации и сборки (с `VERBOSE=1`), а заодно и CMakeCache.txt в студию... можно на какой-нить pastebin, если в сообщение вставлять не хочется...

Comment: @user_1234567890, собственно того что нужно — логов конфигурации (того что выводит cmake) и сборки (того что выводит `make`) там нет... но если верить Makefile'ам и CMakeCache.txt то всё нормально... так что я спрошу ещё раз: после конфигурации (с помощью `cmake` или `cmake-gui`), ты запускаешь `make` (или `nmake`, `mingw32-make`) в каталоге сборки?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, осуществляю выбор MinGW Makefiles, который, вероятно, использует mingw32-make.exe. Если говорить о том, как я это определил, то через переменные среды нашел путь к этому исполняемому файлу, а далее попробовал изменить его название. В результате CMake (как консольный, так и cmake-gui) выдали мне ошибки, мол, не удалось найти программу сборки для MinGW Makefiles.

Comment: @user_1234567890,  cmake сам ничего не собирает — он только генерирует файлы для других систем сборки... так что __после__ того как выполнил `cmake` (или `cmake-gui`) надо самому зайти в каталог сборки и запустить в нём `mingw32-make`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, прогресс: я получил хоть какую-то ошибку. No rule to make target 'minhook'. Вызов осуществлялся следующим образом: mingw32-make.exe -C (директория_CMakeLists.txt) -S (имя цели = minhook) -B (директория_размещения_результата)

Comment: @user_1234567890, просто `mingw32-make.exe -C <каталог сборки>` (тот, в котором `CMakeCache.txt` и `Makefile`)... или просто (подразумевая, что путь к  `mingw32-make.exe` в PATH) `cd path\to\build\dir ;` `mingw32-make`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я искреннее переоценивал CMake, предполагая, что CMake, помимо генерации файлов, должен еще и компилировать, линковать их (ведь по директории в PATH ничто не мешает выяснить и путь к компилятору...). Наконец-таки получил файл minhook.a благодаря вам, за что спасибо большое! Всех благ))